# jQuery Validation plugin's minlength does not work

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I must use min length according to a condition.(I tried in its own it did not work either , anyway)

There is no problem with "required" rule. I can see required message if the condition is ok, "required" rule is working as expected, i can see "happy day" in console too.

But even i can see "min length 5" in console, it behaves like the form is ok.

Where am i wrong? Thanks.

```
if($('form#form_validation_reg_generate_user').valid({


                                        rules: {

                                            'userPassword':{
                                                required:(function () {
                                                    if($('#userPassword').val().length >0 ) {
                                                        console.log('happy day');
                                                        return true;
                                                    }
                                                    else{
                                                        console.log('happy day false');
                                                        return false;
                                                    }
                                                    })(),
                                                minlength:(function () {
                                                    if($('#userPassword').val().length >0 ) {
                                                        console.log('min length 5');
                                                        return 5;

                                                    }
                                                    else{
                                                        console.log('min length 0');
                                                        return 0;
                                                    }
                                                    })()          

                                            }

                                        }

                                    }))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is all wrong:

```
if ($('form#form_validation_reg_generate_user').valid({
    // your rules
}));
```

You are mixing up `.valid()` with `.validate()`.  You are not supposed to declare anything inside of `.valid()` and you can not put `.validate()` inside of a conditional.

[`.validate()` is called *once* to initialize the plugin on the form](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options).  It is not a method for triggering validation on demand.  Once initialized, the form will automatically validate as per the various event callbacks built into the plugin such as `submit`, `onkeyup`, `onfocusout`, and select, button & checkbox `click`.

To perform a validation test programmatically, you can call [the built-in `.valid()` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid) which is very much like the `submit` event in that it will trigger the validation test on the *entire form* and the form will display any errors.  `.valid()` will also return a boolean `true` or `false` indicating if the form passes the validation test.  In your example/case, it does not appear that you'll need to use this method.

---

Your code for rules is illogical:

```
required: (function () {
    if ($('#userPassword').val().length > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
},
minlength: (function () {
    if ($('#userPassword').val().length > 0) {
        return 5;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The logic of your rules makes absolutely no sense and these functions cause the plugin to choke.  The first rule is saying that `userPassword` is `required` only if `userPassword` contains something.  That's logically the same thing as "optional".  Your second rule is saying that the `minlength` of `userPassword` is `5` only if `userPassword` contains something... again that's not making any sense.  If the field is optional, then you just declare the `minlength` and, by default, it only applies when the field contains something. (You did not show your HTML, so I only assume that `userPassword` is both the `name` and `id` of the same field.)

Try this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('form#form_validation_reg_generate_user').validate({
        rules: {
            userPassword: {
                minlength: 5
            } 
        }, 
        submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
            alert('valid form submission'); // for demo
            return false; //form demo
        }
    });

});
```

**DEMO:    http://jsfiddle.net/7jLnu/**

Otherwise, if you also want the field `required`:

```
rules: {
    userPassword: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 5
    } 
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qZzZ6/

Comment: `rules: {
    userPassword: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 5
    } 
},` with these code it warns if there is no char in `userPassword`. I understood that there is no chance to conditionally validate an input, am i right? Thanks

Comment: Also this  `$('form#form_validation_reg_generate_user').validate({
        rules: {
            userPassword: {
                minlength: 5
            } 
        }` does not make sense without required.

Comment: @tuxi, "`minlength` without required" makes perfect sense...  It simply means that the field is optional, however, only IF you fill it in, it must be at least 5 characters.  Yes, you can have conditional rules, but you'll need to explain exactly what you want, rather than my guessing by looking at broken code.

Comment: now i understand, yes it is exactly what you tell, minlength even without required works as i want. But there is a problem when i write my rules in `validate()` in `document.ready`. it does not check according to rules those i wrote in `validate` in `ready`. Thus i wrote them in valid in condition statement.

Comment: @tuxi, Your code was mixed up... you cannot put rules inside a `.valid()` condition statement.  See this working demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/7jLnu/